# Can I declare inner class in different file than outer class?

Tags: scala, syntax

I am looking for a way to declare inner class in a way it has access to outer scope (wrapping class). Both classes will be pretty huge so I want to declare **them in different files**. For example I would like to do something like:

A.scala:

```
class A(_secret:Int){
    val secret = _secret
    var clazz:Class = null
}
```

B.scala:

```
A.clazz = class B{
    def getSecret(){
        A.secret
    }
}
```

The whole purpose is to avoid passing `this` as a constructor parameter down, i. e. `var clazz = new B(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer per se, but usually you do vice versa:

A.scala:

```
class A{
    type clazz = B
}
```

B.scala:

```
class B{

}
```

#### EDIT:

```
trait Foo { self: Bar => 
    def fooSecret = "foo secret"

    def foo() {
        println("I'm foo, but also know bar's secrets: " + self.barSecret)
    }
}

trait Bar { self: Foo =>
    def barSecret = "bar secret"

    def bar() {
        println("I'm bar, but also know foo's secrets: " + self.fooSecret)
    }
}

class Impl extends Foo with Bar
val x = new Impl
x.foo()
x.bar()
```

which results in

```
I'm foo, but also know bar's secrets: bar secret
I'm bar, but also know foo's secrets: foo secret
```

Note that I used def's and different method names (it is important during mixing-in, since inheritance involved)

Comment: `class B` will have access to fields from `A`? (I can't check it now).

Comment: No, unless they are defined as objects. Your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23077438/revisions) actually, clarifies situation a little bit -- there is no *master-slave* dependency, in fact it looks like a *circular dependency*. How about using *self types* for your case?