# inner classes in different files

Tags: scala, inner-classes

My classes are a bit large, so I want to split `Outer` and `Inner` into different files, but I still want to retain the structure, meaning that I have to type `Outer.Inner` because that's what makes the most sense in my application.

```scala
// Outer.scala

class Outer
object Outer {
    class Inner
    object Inner
}
```

How would I go about doing that?

As far as I know Scala doesn't have partial classes like C#, so I'm a little lost on how to go about it.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077438/can-i-declare-inner-class-in-different-file-than-outer-class) and I'm not sure that it's helping me in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps split them out in traits and then mixin

```
// Foo.scala
trait Foo {
  class Inner
  object Inner
}

// Outer.scala
object Outer extends Foo
```

so now `Outer.Inner` still works.

Comment: Is there any popular naming scheme for this sort of thing? Like calling the traits `_Inner` or `TraitInner`?